# Better way to add/remove HTML divs on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webapp that has a form. The main relevent element is a row containing a two-columns for input. (Two html inputs).

Users need to be able to add or remove rows, but there should always be at least one row. If there is only one row, the inputs should be cleared and the left input should gain focus.

By default, when the page loads, I have this defined in my HTML:

```
      <div class='row' id="group1">
        <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label class='control-label' for='input1'>Input</label>
            <input class='form-control' id='input1' name='input' type='text' />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='output1'>Output</label>
            <div class = 'input-group'>
              <input class='form-control' id='output1' name='output' type='text' />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class='btn btn-success' id='remove1' type='button' onClick='removeClick(1)'>X</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In my javascript file for this page, in the onClick for the button that would add a new row, and on a remove click I remove the row or clear it:

```
var inputCount = 1;

$("#add-button").click(function(){
    inputCount++;
    $('#advanced-row').before(" \
      <div class='row' id='group" + inputCount +"'> \
        <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4'> \
          <div class='form-group'> \
            <label class='visible visible-xs' for='input" + inputCount + "'>Input " + inputCount + "'</label> \
            <input class='form-control' id='input" + inputCount + "' name='input' type='text'/> \
          </div> \
        </div> \
        <div class='col-sm-4'> \
          <div class='form-group'> \
            <label class='visible visible-xs' for='output" + inputCount + "'>Output 2</label> \
            <div class = 'input-group'> \
              <input class='form-control' id='output" + inputCount + "' name='output' type='text' /> \
              <span class='input-group-btn'> \
                <button class='btn btn-success' id='remove2' type='button' onClick='removeClick(" + inputCount + ")'>X</button> \
              </span> \
            </div> \
          </div> \
        </div> \
      </div>");
    return false;
});


function removeClick(row)
{
    if (inputCount > 1) {
        $("#group" + row).remove();
        inputCount--;
    } else {
        clearInput(row);
    }
}

function clearInput(row)
{
    $("#input" + row).val('');
    $("#output" + row).val('');
    $("#input" + row).focus();
}
```

This works just fine for me. However, I don't like having to write the HTML out as a string like that in JS and it doesn't give me a way to easily swap out or make modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep track of the count there - since you've made jQuery available, just use the count of elements returned by the jQuery selector:

```
if ($('input').length > 1) {
    // allow removal
} else {
    // clear inputs and set focus on another
}
```

Even if you don't want to use jQuery, it's straightforward to use vanilla js as you're dealing with a nodelist that has a length property:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('input').length > 1)
```

Also, I'd recommend not using onclick but rather just define jquery handlers in your script.

Comment: If I have three rows and the X in the middle row is clicked, how can I make that X delete just that row using jquery? Especially if I were to just use a handler and not assign the function to the onclick?

Comment: To clarify, you want this behavior to be limited to each form group and not apply the logic to all inputs at once?

Comment: Exactly. I want the same behavior for each form group, but I want it to apply to only the form group clicked on.

Comment: @Llewey you can get a `this` object when mouse click in the handler. So you can use something like $(this).closest('.row').remove() to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$("#group1").clone()` and change the elements' ids.